# How can I reproduce this DDD test?

Tags: c, gdb, config, gnu-make, gnu

I'm learning how to use Data Display Debugger (DDD) for my C/C++ programs. The [Help reference for DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) shows some sample outputs, including the following graphic graph / charting example.  I'm trying to reproduce the exercise, but I'm having difficulty.  The way it should work is I would compile cxxtest.c with debugger options, and the DDD tool would actually graph the variable array of interest during a step debugging session, in both 2D and 3D.  Wow, if it works.

[image: DDD and graph / chart images]

The cxxtest.c program is included in the [DDD repository](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddd/), ddd-3.3.12.tar.gz.  I'm trying to compile and run that program but I keep getting stuck.  I can't figure out how to generate a config.h file, so I can link in necessary support files (e.g. bool.h) to compile cxxtest.c

Files I see in the DDD repository, relating to config include:

- config-info
- config.h.in
- config.texi
- configinfo.C
- configinfo.h
- configure
- configure.in

None of them seem to offer much help on how to generate a config.h file.

Anybody know how to generate a config.h file ?

Update: As I continue to work this one, the whole thing seems odd.  The program , `cxxtest.C` , has a `.C` suffix, but there are distinctly C++ elements in there, `#include <iostream>`  If I block the config.h thing, change the suffix to .cpp and compile I get a whole bunch of different errors. Not sure what the intent was here.

As for README content, I do see some instructions on how to compile the entire DDD tool, and it's quite lengthy.  It's not clear on if preparing / configuring and compiling the DDD tool will also compile this particular test file.  I guess I can wade thru the make files and scripts and see if this file every gets mentioned. (sigh!)

Actually I'm considering converting the entire file over to pure .c via rewrite.  Note, the original file is [visible here...](https://fossies.org/linux/ddd/ddd/cxxtest.C)

Note: I'm working in Virtualbox Ubuntu desktop for now...  Ultimately I'd like to use the DDD tool to analyze key arrays in some digital signal processing (DSP) programs I'm working on.

Update #2:
  I tried two different things here.  First I built a C version of a file with the plot routines copied from the original cxxtest.c program.  I converted all the calls to pure C.  I could easily see the data in the DDD data window in text format. When I select the data set and then choose plot, I get a popup "DDD: Starting Plot... Starting gnuplot..."  The system just hangs there.

Second, I did a complete clean install of the ddd tool.  I had to install a few dependencies, and correct a few known bugs (e.g. `#include <cstdio>` ) but was successful at both `$ ./configure && make` and `$ make check` . The `make check` command does correctly build and compile cxxtest.c . When I run the file and do the steps to plot the `dr` and `ir` array variables, I get the same failure as above.

System hang. A search of the failure indicates this has been reported for years, apparently without resolve.  Not quite sure how to proceed.  This appears to be a total fail.  I cannot reproduce the DDD test to plot graphical output.  Anybody else make progress on this one?

Note: with this edit, I'm also removing the `How do I generate config.h?` from the title.  That's not really the key issue here.

Comment: Is there a README?

Comment: The `INSTALL` file  says "For a simple check before installation, type $ make check This creates a sample C++ program \`cxxtest' and then runs DDD  on it by invoking \`./ddd cxxtest'"

Comment: See additional notes:  when I just have cxxtest.c and a few support files in a stand alone directory, `make check` returns `make: *** No rule to make target 'check'. Stop.`  I'm pretty familiar on running `ddd`, just not with graphical output.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I was able to find that reference... It's quite possible I'm missing some dependencies as well, sigh;  libstdc++ or libg++, Motif, Xlib and xt, Big sigh.  I'm still thinking a rewrite to pure .c might be way easier.  I've already got precompiled `ddd` available.

Comment: So I extracted key elements from the overall ddd make files, and created a 25 line Makefile surrounding `cxxtest` object generation, but ultimately I'm still stuck with the `config.h` error (which I can hide) and then the `iostream` error, etc...

Comment: The `.C` suffix is an old convention for C++ files. You don't have to compile ddd to compile cxxtest, but if you can run `./configure` successfully, it will create `config.h` and then you just need to run `g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./.. -g -Wall -W -Wwrite-strings -trigraphs ./cxxtest.C -o cxxtest -lm`

Comment: Since you're on Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get build-dep ddd` will retrieve and install the library and tool dependencies you need.

Comment: I do not pretend this to be a complete answer, but if you just want to learn `ddd` and `gnuplot` integration, these videos might get you started: [ddd gnuplot example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmxzQfP5oAE), [Plot 3D data with DDD and Gnuplot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yC5Pv-vW0Q).

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody know how to generate a config.h file ?

Yes: just run the `configure` script provided. A typical sequence for building open source software is:

```
./configure && make
```

Comment: May I suggest that you should learn to read beyond the headlines when reading the news. Note edit above.

Comment: @zipzit Let me get this straight: you are complaining that I've answered your question is it was yesterday, instead of answering after you updated it an hour ago? Do you have a time travel machine you can sell me?

Comment: It was your answer that convinced me I needed to update the question. 
 There is not really enough room to place exactly all the questions in the title.  Exactly where did you think I was going with this  `graph/charting example`and `reproduce the exercise`??  When you generated the `config.h` file, were you able to successfully get a plot of data in the ddd tool?  And do note, I didn't downvote your answer... I upvoted it by one (-1 --> 0)